# Custom navigation bar in beamer?

Tags: beamer, navigation

I need to get the navigation bar format in the diagram below on my frames. Any suggestions?

```
 \documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%-----------------Navigation Panel-----------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\makeatletter
\pgfdefobject{beamerslidenavlight}{\pgfpoint{-10pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfpoint{20pt}{5pt}}
 {\pgfpathqmoveto{-3bp}{0.5bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{-7bp}{3bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{-3bp}{5.5bp}
  \pgfusepathqfill
  \pgfpathqmoveto{13bp}{0.5bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{17bp}{3bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{13bp}{5.5bp}
  \pgfusepathqfill}

\def\insertslidenavigationsymbol{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-5pt}{-1.5pt}{20pt}{5.5pt}
    \color{black}\pgfuseobject{beamerslidenavlight}%
  \end{pgfpicture}\kern-30pt%
  \hyperlinkslideprev{\beamer@linkspace{16pt}}%
  \Acrobatmenu{GoToPage}{\beamer@linkspace{8pt}}%
  \hyperlinkslidenext{\beamer@linkspace{6pt}}}
\makeatother

\defbeamertemplate*{navigation symbols}{myvertical}{%
\vbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[fill=gray!20,draw,anchor=south east]
  (symbols)
  at ([yshift=50pt]current page.south east)
  {\insertslidenavigationsymbol};
  \node[text width=30pt,fill=gray!20,inner ysep=3pt,below=2 pt of symbols.south,text=black,font=\itshape,align=center]
  (page)
  {Page~\textcolor{red}{\insertframenumber}\ of~\textcolor{red}{\inserttotalframenumber}};
  \draw[gray!70,line width=1pt]
    (page.north west) -- (page.north east)
    (page.south west) -- (page.south east)
    (symbols.north) -- (symbols.south)
    (symbols.north west) -- (symbols.north east)
    (symbols.south west) -- (symbols.south east)
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
}
%%%%%% ------------------------------------ FONT FAMILIES----------------------------------------- %%%%%%%%

%\usepackage{courier}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
                            %%%%%%-------Latin Modern Typewriter---------%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}




%%%%%%----------------------TITLE---------------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title[]{}

%%%%%%%%%--------------------------AUTHOR-------------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




%%%%%%%%%-------------------------------COLLEGE AND DATE------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\institute{}
\date{\today}

%%%%%%%%%--------------------------COLOR THEME-----------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %\usecolortheme[RGB]{227, 11, 92}{structure}
\usecolortheme[RGB={178, 34, 34}]{structure}

%%%%%%%%%------------------------FOOTLINE--------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{ru theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \centering
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.50\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \leftskip=0.5cm
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
 % \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
%    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortdate
%  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.08\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

%%%%%%%%%------------------------HEADERLINE---------------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%HEADER LINE

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{}{%
  %
    \leavevmode%
    \hspace*{0.065\paperwidth}
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.86\paperwidth,ht=10.25ex,dp=1ex,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{}
  {%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-\beamer@headheight%
    \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
      \vfil
      \leftskip=-\beamer@leftmargin%
      \advance\leftskip by 0.07\paperwidth%0.3cm%
      \rightskip=-\beamer@rightmargin%
      \advance\rightskip by0.3cm plus1fil%
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\par}%
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\par}%
      \vbox{}%
      \vskip-1em%
      \vfil
    }%
  }
\makeatother
%
%%%%%%%%%---------------------------TITLE PAGE-------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true,ht=11ex]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

 %%%%%%%%---------------------------- PRESENTATION SLIDES -----------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 %%%%%%%%%-------------------------------TITLEPAGE---------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%----------------------------------------TABLE OF CONTENTS----------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{frame}{\bfseries Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%----------------------------INTRODUCTION-----------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I just noticed that even though you have received good answer to some of your questions, you still haven't accepted any. Accepting an answer that helped you is the preferred way to thank people around here, so I invite you to revisit your questions and accept the answers that you consider helped you solved your problems. In case of doubt, please see  [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: @gonzalo-medina:  thank you, to give answer to my question but it didn't shown in my edited presentation

Comment: Did you compile your document two or three times?

Comment: @gonzalo-medina:  yes, and i create new file to run it. In that also it not be show.

Comment: That's why you should always post in your questions the actual code you are using. Can you please edit your quation and add there a *complete*, yet short document (like the one in my answer) but with your settings and showing the problem you mention?

Comment: Please see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 5):

### Update

With the actual settings (you need to comment out or delete `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` and add `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` as in my origincal code):

```
 \documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%-----------------Navigation Panel-----------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\pgfdefobject{beamerslidenavlight}{\pgfpoint{-10pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfpoint{20pt}{5pt}}
 {\pgfpathqmoveto{-3bp}{0.5bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{-7bp}{3bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{-3bp}{5.5bp}
  \pgfusepathqfill
  \pgfpathqmoveto{13bp}{0.5bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{17bp}{3bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{13bp}{5.5bp}
  \pgfusepathqfill}

\def\insertslidenavigationsymbol{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-10pt}{-1.5pt}{20pt}{5.5pt}
    \color{black}\pgfuseobject{beamerslidenavlight}%
  \end{pgfpicture}\kern-30pt%
  \hyperlinkslideprev{\beamer@linkspace{16pt}}%
  \Acrobatmenu{GoToPage}{\beamer@linkspace{8pt}}%
  \hyperlinkslidenext{\beamer@linkspace{6pt}}}
\makeatother

\defbeamertemplate*{navigation symbols}{myvertical}{%
\vbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[fill=gray!20,anchor=south east]
  (symbols)
  at ([yshift=50pt]current page.south east)
  {\insertslidenavigationsymbol};
  \node[text width=30pt,fill=gray!20,inner ysep=3pt,below=2 pt of symbols.south,text=black,font=\normalsize\Tiny\itshape,align=center]
  (page)
  {Page~\textcolor{red}{\insertframenumber}\ of~\textcolor{red}{\inserttotalframenumber}};
  \draw[gray!70,line width=1pt]
    (page.north west) -- (page.north east)
    (page.south west) -- (page.south east)
    (symbols.north) -- (symbols.south)
    (symbols.north west) -- (symbols.north east)
    (symbols.south west) -- (symbols.south east)
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%% ------------------------------------ FONT FAMILIES----------------------------------------- %%%%%%%%

%\usepackage{courier}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
                            %%%%%%-------Latin Modern Typewriter---------%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}




%%%%%%----------------------TITLE---------------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title[]{}

%%%%%%%%%--------------------------AUTHOR-------------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




%%%%%%%%%-------------------------------COLLEGE AND DATE------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\institute{}
\date{\today}

%%%%%%%%%--------------------------COLOR THEME-----------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %\usecolortheme[RGB]{227, 11, 92}{structure}
\usecolortheme[RGB={178, 34, 34}]{structure}

%%%%%%%%%------------------------FOOTLINE--------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{ru theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \centering
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.50\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \leftskip=0.5cm
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
 % \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
%    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortdate
%  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.08\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

%%%%%%%%%------------------------HEADERLINE---------------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%HEADER LINE

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{}{%
  %
    \leavevmode%
    \hspace*{0.065\paperwidth}
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.86\paperwidth,ht=10.25ex,dp=1ex,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{}
  {%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-\beamer@headheight%
    \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
      \vfil
      \leftskip=-\beamer@leftmargin%
      \advance\leftskip by 0.07\paperwidth%0.3cm%
      \rightskip=-\beamer@rightmargin%
      \advance\rightskip by0.3cm plus1fil%
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\par}%
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\par}%
      \vbox{}%
      \vskip-1em%
      \vfil
    }%
  }
\makeatother
%
%%%%%%%%%---------------------------TITLE PAGE-------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true,ht=11ex]
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

 %%%%%%%%---------------------------- PRESENTATION SLIDES -----------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 %%%%%%%%%-------------------------------TITLEPAGE---------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%----------------------------------------TABLE OF CONTENTS----------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{frame}{\bfseries Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%----------------------------INTRODUCTION-----------------------------------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



  \end{document}
```

[image]

Here you go:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\pgfdefobject{beamerslidenavlight}{\pgfpoint{-10pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfpoint{20pt}{5pt}}
 {\pgfpathqmoveto{-3bp}{0.5bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{-7bp}{3bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{-3bp}{5.5bp}
  \pgfusepathqfill
  \pgfpathqmoveto{13bp}{0.5bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{17bp}{3bp}
  \pgfpathqlineto{13bp}{5.5bp}
  \pgfusepathqfill}

\def\insertslidenavigationsymbol{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-10pt}{-1.5pt}{20pt}{5.5pt}
    \color{black}\pgfuseobject{beamerslidenavlight}%
  \end{pgfpicture}\kern-30pt%
  \hyperlinkslideprev{\beamer@linkspace{16pt}}%
  \Acrobatmenu{GoToPage}{\beamer@linkspace{8pt}}%
  \hyperlinkslidenext{\beamer@linkspace{6pt}}}
\makeatother

\defbeamertemplate*{navigation symbols}{myvertical}{%
\vbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[fill=gray!20,draw,anchor=south east] 
  (symbols) 
  at ([yshift=50pt]current page.south east)
  {\insertslidenavigationsymbol};
  \node[text width=30pt,fill=gray!20,inner ysep=3pt,below=2 pt of symbols.south,text=black,font=\itshape,align=center]
  (page)
  {Page~\textcolor{red}{\insertframenumber}\ of~\textcolor{red}{\inserttotalframenumber}};
  \draw[gray!70,line width=1pt]
    (page.north west) -- (page.north east)
    (page.south west) -- (page.south east)
    (symbols.north) -- (symbols.south)
    (symbols.north west) -- (symbols.north east)
    (symbols.south west) -- (symbols.south east)
    ;  
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]